# Does .NET put your libraries into the GAC?

Tags: .net, gac

Just been debugging a problem for a while where when my application was deployed, it couldn't find a class inside a DLL file.

Eventually it turned out there was an older copy in the GAC that it was using.

As I didn't set up the server, I don't know how it got there.

How do libraries that I create and compile myself in .NET end up in the GAC? Is it an automatic process as part of publishing to IIS, or similar, or does it mean that somebody manually installed it there?

I'm just looking to mitigate future deployment issues, as it was a pain to track this down.

Comment: No.  It is in fact quite hard to do, gacutil.exe is an SDK utility and is not available on a non-programmer machine.  Creating an installer to do it is not so hard to do, it does leave a trail.  Nursing [AssemblyVersion] is important and too often ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that doesn't happen automatically.

From the [GAC documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/gac) this would normally happen due to:

- Using an installer designed to do this
- Running gacutil

If this is an ASP.NET application, I'd be somewhat surprised if someone had created an installer for this - it seems more likely that someone ran gacutil on the server.

(Fortunately the GAC has gone away in .NET Core, so over time this is likely to be less of an issue anyway. Not that .NET Core is without its versioning problems...)

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. Someone must have stuck it in there manually. Hopefully they didn't do the same thing to production...

Comment: I think you meant "not that" instead of "note that". I tried to offer an edit, but they must be at least six characters.